# How to call a URL periodically form a linux box (cron job)?

Tags: cron, wget

I have a shell access on a Linux box where my Website resides.

I want to call a URL each hour on that Website (it's not a specific PHP file, I have codeigniter has a framework and some Apache redirects, so I really need to call a URL).

I guess I can use wget and crontab? How?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add this to /etc/crontab

```
0 * * * * wget -O - -q -t 1 http://www.example.com/cron.php
```

Alternatively, create a shell script in the /etc/cron.hourly

File: wget

```
#!/bin/sh
wget -O - -q -t 1 http://www.example.com/cron.php
```

make sure you chmod +x wget (or whatever filename you picked)

Comment: For those coming along wondering what the options mean: Quietly (-q) try 1 time (-t 1) to wget http://www.example.com/cron.php and don't send the output anywhere (-O -).